# Implementing Keycloak Authentication for Sonarr in Docker

Tags: docker, authentication, single-sign-on, keycloak

I currently have two applications, Sonarr and Keycloak, both running in Docker on my Ubuntu laptop. Presently, the Sonarr application doesn't have authentication, and my objective is to establish a setup where every user attempting to access Sonarr undergoes verification through Keycloak.

While exploring solutions, I came across GoAuthentik's "outpost" feature with a [proxy provider](https://goauthentik.io/docs/outposts/), as illustrated in this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/OBJa2G3Ef7o?si=51iZx4OzZrMRh3st). Regrettably, I couldn't find a similar feature in Keycloak during my research for comparison.

Has anyone else encountered a similar issue, or does anyone have resources that could assist me in addressing this challenge? Your assistance would be highly valued.